# Sql query returns no rows for where condition on Month column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table 'FACT', for which the month_title column was populated using to_char(some_date, 'Month') due to which the data type for the month_title column is VARCHAR2(36 BYTE).

| INSTR_ID | TRAINER_ID | LESSON_DAY | MONTH_TITLE | TOTAL_ENROLLED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| INS100 | T101 | Tuesday | June | 2 |
| INS100 | T101 | Tuesday | May | 1 |
| INS100 | T101 | Wednesday | June | 2 |
| INS100 | T101 | Wednesday | May | 3 |
| INS100 | T102 | Thursday | May | 3 |
| INS100 | T102 | Friday | May | 1 |
| INS100 | T102 | Saturday | May | 1 |
| INS100 | T107 | Monday | May | 1 |
| INS200 | T103 | Saturday | June | 3 |

Running the below query gives me no result:

```
SELECT
    instrumentid, instructorid, lesson_day, month_title, total_enrolled
FROM
    fact
where month_title = 'May';
```

Whereas I am expecting records with the month_title set to only 'May'. Could using to_char be causing the problem?

Answer (score 2):

When working with dates you should always use the database specific `date` datatype. That way, you wouldn't get these kind of problems.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the problem is your `to_char` call.

If you use the format mask `"Month"`, Oracle will return a fixed width, blank padded value.  So the value in the table isn't actually "May", it's "May      " with 6 spaces after the "y".  You almost certainly want `to_char( some_date, 'fmMonth' )` which removes the trailing spaces (or you could `trunc( to_char( some_date, 'Month' ))`).

Comment: Oracle could do you the favor of removing the trailing spaces when they are stored (or at least ignoring them as some databases do).